# Проверка существования файла через форму

Tags: php, javascript

Есть форма, input. В которую пользователь вводит название файла. Вот она:

```
<form action="found.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Введите название файла: <input type=text name="name"><br>
<input type="submit" name="send" value="Делаем проверку!" style="margin-top: 10px;">
</form>
```

И обработчик found.php

```
<?php
$name=$_REQUEST['name'];
echo "Вы ввели название файла: $name" ; 
if (file_exists($name)) {
    echo "\n Да, этот файл действительно есть";
} else {
    echo "\n Нет, такого файла не существует";
}

?>
```

По задумке человек вводит название файла и проверяет, есть ли этот файл.
Но т.к. скрипт находится не в папке /load, а в корне, то эту папку он не проверяет. Понимаю, что как-то к запросу нужно добавлять /load/название файла, но не понимаю, как это сделать. Почему в load? - Потому что файлы для проверки лежат там.

Comment: "есть ли этот файл" - Где, на сервере или на клиенте?

Comment: Сервер, правда я все на локалке делаю, дальше нее это не пойдет, мне для принципа работы понять надо, как можно тут сделать

Comment: функция  realpath

Answer (score 2):

Сделал вот так, вроде, работает.

```
<?php
$dir = 'I://OpenServer/domains/prof/load/';        #Указываем директорию
$file = scandir($dir);
$name=$_REQUEST['name'];
if (in_array($name, $file)) {
      echo "\n Да,  файл c именем $name действительно есть";
} else {
    echo "\n Нет, файла c именем $name не существует";
}

?>
```